Irreducibility of a subvariety
Assume that $Y\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ is a projective variety and $Y$ contains a smooth projective curve $C$. If for almost all $p\in C$, the tangent space of $Y$ at $p$ is 1-dimensional. Is $C$ necessarily an irreducible component of $Y$?

This already holds as soon as there is a single (closed) point $p \in C$ with this property. See for instance [Tag 0A21(5)], since $\dim \mathcal O_{Y,p} \leq \dim \mathfrak m_p/\mathfrak m_p^2 = 1$. (This proves that any component through $p$ must have dimension $1$, so any component containing $C$ must have dimension $1$.)
